# Book where magic presents itself as blue letters in front of the user

Tags: story-identification, books

- Main character’s name starts with “balt” I think
- It takes place maybe a few centuries ago
- Magic presents itself as blue letters in front of the user
- Maybe in Spain, and magic is outlawed due to religion (almost 100% Catholicism)
- Fantasy/fiction, probably YA or  Teen book, but I read it when I was 10.
- Within the first few chapters he is on a boat
- I believe he wasn’t raised by his parents

(I would take everything I say broadly. I read this 5 yrs ago)

Comment: Just to clarify, you read this in 2015, five years ago, when you were 10?

Comment: Because it matches up with magic appearing as text, was this LitRPG, where people can see their progression, add in a game?

Comment: Im almost 100% sure it was 2015